# How to visualize Map/matching result in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis-2

I want to visualize this map-matching results in QGIS 2.0.

http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/browser/trunk/core/sql/matching.html

I load my network in QGIS 2.0 and I want to visualize the output of matching_line_as_linestring.sql.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question is expected to include proof of basic research effort and - if applicable - code so far. Questions requesting code or instructions to copy&paste are generally not well received.